# Replace multiple special character HTML using regex

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext2, dreamweaver

I'm trying to replace some strings using regex in HTML, but there are Swedish characters that make my life difficult.

It starts off looking like this (I'm using dummy text instead of the real Swedish):

```
<td class="swedish">abc defg&aring; hijk lmnop&auml;</td>
    <td><?php audioButton("../../audio/lessons/01/some_old_text","some_old_text"); ?></td>
    <td><?php audioButton("../../audio/lessons/01/slow/some_old_text_slx","some_old_text_slx","1"); ?></td>
```

Step 1: I manage to place the string in the first tag inside the audiobutton, so it looks like this:

```
<td class="swedish">abc defg&aring; hijk lmnop&auml;</td>
    <td><?php audioButton("../../audio/lessons/01/abc defg&aring; hijk lmnop&auml;","abc defg&aring; hijk lmnop&auml;"); ?></td>
    <td><?php audioButton("../../audio/lessons/01/slow/abc defg&aring; hijk lmnop&auml;_slx","abc defg&aring; hijk lmnop&auml;_slx","1"); ?></td>
```

You don't have to read this, but I did it with the following:

Find

```
<td class="swedish">(.*)</td>\n.*<td><\?php audioButton\("(.*)/.*",".*"\); \?></td>\n.*<td><\?php audioButton\("(.*)/.*",".*","1"\); \?></td>
```

Replace

```
<td class="swedish">$1</td>
<td><?php audioButton("$2/$1","$1"); ?></td>
<td><?php audioButton("$3/$1_slx","$1_slx","1");?></td>
```

It's fairly straightforward, even for a noob like myself.

Step 2: Now this is where my problems begin. The Swedish characters ä, ö and å have special codes in HTML (`&auml; - &ouml; and &aring;`). I have to replace each instance of that code with ae, oe and aa respectively, and put an underscore between each word. This has to happen inside the audiobutton only.

The final result has to look like this:

```
<td class="swedish">abc defg&aring; hijk lmnop&auml;</td>
    <td><?php audioButton("../../audio/lessons/01/abc_defgaa_hijk_lmnopae","abc_defgaa_hijk_lmnopae"); ?></td>
    <td><?php audioButton("../../audio/lessons/01/slow/abc_defgaa_hijk_lmnopae_slx","abc_defgaa_hijk_lmnopae_slx","1"); ?></td>
```

This is where my regex literacy fails me. It's probably really simple, but I can't see it. I would really appreciate some help. It would be especially great if I can do the whole thing in one step instead of two.

Comment: It needs multiple find/replace hits which I don't like. Thus I'd suggest [writing macros](http://superuser.com/questions/605861/how-do-i-record-and-run-multiple-find-replace-with-sublime-text-2) to speed up things.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look it up. I hope it's straightforward enough ;)

Comment: Can someone help me out with the second step in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash loop that will replace the audioButton occurrences as you wish:

```
for line in $(egrep "audioButton" swedish.txt | sed -e 's?\ ?::ZZqC::?g') ; do
    real_line=$(echo "${line}" | sed -e 's?::ZZqC::?\ ?g') ;
    new_line=$(echo "${real_line}" | sed -e 's?&auml;?ae?g' -e 's?&ouml;?oe?g' -e 's?&aring;?aa?g' -e 's?\([a-z]\) ?\1_?g') ;
    sed -i -e "s|${real_line}|${new_line}|g" swedish.txt ;
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! To be honest, this is way beyond my competence. I don't know how to use it :( 

I just put my HTML into Sublime Text and mess around with the regex until something works. It would be even better if it would work in Dreamweaver, because then I can search and replace all my files, but I don't think anyone uses Dreamweaver anymore.